# How to insert a line to html file after match using SED

Tags: html, bash, sed, terminal

How can i insert a line to an html file after a match, for example I am trying to insert this line :

```
<a href="www.google.com">HERE</a>
```

after a match like this :

```
<p id="insert_here">
```

After some research, I found out that Sed can be used for something like this, here is my try :

```
sed '/\<p id="insert_here">/<a href="www.google.com">HERE </a>' prac.html
```

Comment: Use this : `sed '/<p id="insert_here">/i \<a href="www.google.com">HERE </a>' prac.html`

Comment: I get this error
    "/<p id="insert_here">/i ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command

Comment: ^^ Drop the `\ ` before `<a` from sat's comment.

Comment: Still not working, it says command i expects \ followed by text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a line, use the `a` (for append) command :

```
sed -i '/<a href="www.google.com">HERE<\/a>/a\
<p id="insert_here">
' prac.html
```

With GNU sed, you can omit the new line after command :

```
sed -i '/<a href="www.google.com">HERE<\/a>/a <p id="insert_here">' prac.html
```

Comment: Alright am getting this error with the second one:
sed: 1: "/<a href="www.google.co ...": invalid command code \

Comment: @Abugado I updated (missing code in the first command). The second one may not work with some sed versions.

Comment: am still getting this error, sed: 1: "prac.html": extra characters at the end of p command.
However, i tried this: 
sed '/<p id="insert_here">/a \
<a href="www.google.com">HERE<\/a>' prac.html 
And it works, but it doesn't change the file, it just displays the change, I tried using -i, but it gives an error:
sed: 1: "prac.html": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: I you're under Mac OS X, replace `sed -i` with `sed -i ''`.

Answer (score 1):

correct command is should be like
`sed -e 's#<p id="insert_here">#<a href="www.google.com">HERE </a>#g' prac.html`

/g is used to replace it globally
for further details read [sed by example](http://www.funtoo.org/Sed_by_Example,_Part_2)

you can also use -i flag for in place replacement 
example:

```
sed -i '' 's#<p id="insert_here">#<a href="www.google.com">HERE </a>#g' prac.html
```

Comment: doesn't 's' mean substitute? am just trying to add a new line, also am still getting an error :
sed: 1: "s/<p id="insert_here">/ ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'a'

Comment: Have you tested this? The unescaped slash in `</a>` will confuse sed.

Comment: @rohitverma it is kind of working, but it is replacing it not adding a new line.

Comment: @BenjaminW. so what do you think i should do to not confuse sed? i tried adding a back slash it didn't work.